# MPEG layer 3 compression

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

How can I apply MPEG-1 layer 3 compression (with 64 kbps or 48 or any value) to the audio signal?

I searched via google but somehow I couldn't get the answer. So something came from my mind! Let me share it ..

At first I read an audio via wavread function

Then write this to mp3 format

Could it be possible? Is there any built-in mp3 write (MATLAB) function?

If this is a bad idea (I think so), then the question is, how can I do it?

Comment: I believe that the MP3 codec requires a license for encoding if sold with a commercial product such as Matlab. Have you tried [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13852-mp3read-and-mp3write) on the MathWorks File Exchange? Otherwise use `audiowrite` to save your audio as a lossless WAV and use another application to convert to MP3. You should also use `audioread` rather than the deprecated `wavread`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MP3 codecs have quite a complicated licensing agreement. AUDIOWRITE supports writing MPEG-4 audio using AAC encoding. This is better than MP3 in that it provides better quality at lower bitrates. This is supported on Windows and Mac.

If you are looking to write compressed audio, you can give this a shot. However, if it is MP3 that you want, you might want to look at file exchange.

Dinesh